# What are the drawbacks if the Singleton constructor is made protected - Inheritance - C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I want the class to inherit the singleton class. Thus, I need to make the constructor protected rather than private. Also, I know that the static methods cannot be overriden because static are the class members. Now, the question is if I will make the constructor protected, will there be any issue? Is protected constructor in the singleton scenario has a drawback? I am talking in the reference of C++.

Comment: The main drawback is that you have a singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Answer (score 0):

I don't think making the constructor protected has any drawbacks. The protected access specifier was meant to be used for inheritance. 
If you do not make the base class constructor protected, how will you ever create your derived class object?

Below is a simple implementation.

```
class Base {
public:
    static Base* getInstance() {
        if(Base::_instance == NULL)
            Base::_instance = new Base(); 
        return Base::_instance;
     }
protected:
    Base() {}
private:
    static Base* _instance;
};
```

in the .cpp file :

```
Base::_instance = NULL;



class Derived : public Base {
public:
    static Derived* getInstance() { 
        if(instance == NULL)
            _instance = new Derived;
        return _instance;
    }
private:
    static Derived* _instance;
};
```

Comment: That's not a singleton, it's a memory-leak factory.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You are right, but this is a bit harsh. just edit it.

Comment: how is it a memory leak?

Comment: @Rush You must have a static member pointer. when you create the instance you affect the pointer. in the getInstance() method you need to check if the pointer is NULL. if the pointer is NULL there is not instance and you must create it, if it isn't null just return the pointer.

Comment: @Rush: Each call to `getInstance()` creates a new instance, leaving the user with the responsibility to delete it. The user, having been told it's a singleton, won't think to delete it, so it will be leaked.

Comment: @Rush your current approach creates a new instance everytime you call getInstance() and doesn't even delete the old one. This is not a singleton. and there is definitely a memory leak. I'll edit your answer to show you

Comment: @FélixCantournet: I can't edit it, since I've no idea how to transform this weirdness into a sensible example of a singleton with a protected constructor.

Comment: @rush did you mean to make instance a static variable? You are still not deleting it anywhere

Comment: Thanks folks for the suggestion. I was maybe asleep while writing those :)
Yes, singletons are supposed to outlive the app/process so no question of deleting them.
This is not a full blown singleton, but rather a simple example.

Comment: I guess that the destructor should also be protected right?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : DO NOT.
You might have a good reason for using a singleton (unlikely but what the hell).
I hardly think you can have a good reason for having a singleton derive from another singleton.

This is completely useless. When you create an instance of `Derived` you will create an instance of `Base`.

Just make `Derived`a singleton and `Base` an standard class with a public constructor.

The Singleton desing pattern refers to the interface for create instance of the Class. This only means something for concrete classes that you will instanciate. Not potentially abstract Base classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the other posts misinterpreted what the OP meant, so I'll just give my two cents :). I think the OP is talking about a construction like the following:

```
template<class A>
class Singleton // class that defines what is means to be Singleton
{
   private:

   protected:
      Singleton() = default;

   public:
      static A& instance()
      {
         static A a;
         return a;
      }
};

class DerivedSingleton: public Singleton<DerivedSingleton> // Make concrete Singleton
{
   friend Singleton<DerivedSingleton>;
   private:
      DerivedSingleton();
   public:
      void DerivedMethod();
};

// .. some code ...
DerivedSingleton::instance().DerivedMethod(); // call method
```

In this case I do not see any issues with making the `Singleton` constructor `protected`. The only way to get hold of `DerivedSingleton` is through the `instance` function of the `Singleton` class. Whether or not Singleton is a good design pattern I have no opinion on.